# Developing WordPress Theme using CSS framework like Bootstrap

Tags: theme-development, themes, twitter-bootstrap

I am going to develop WordPress theme using [Underscores](https://underscores.me/) and Bootstrap.

So should I copy [all bootstrap codes](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css) in to style.css or should I include it using `@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css");` in style.css?

Comment: Check my Answer's Update: And if you found this helpful please mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither, 
In wordpress styles and scripts should be properly en-queued through your functions.php file rather than hard-coding them in your html.

The wordpress way of adding a new css file, be it `bootstrap.css` or any other is to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

The following code should be in your theme's `functions.php`

```
/**
* Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
*/
function wp_theme_name_scripts() {

    // enqueue your style.css
    wp_enqueue_style('style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // en-queue external style
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css' );

    // enqueue your script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/theme_name.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    // Other styles and scripts
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_theme_name_scripts' );
```

[This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402) is a great tutorial on how to load css the right way in wordpress.

[Check out](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) WordPress documentation for more info on enqueueing styles

### Update:

Underscores Framework already has the function defined in the `functions.php`.
Open your themes `function.php` and find the function named `yourTheme_scripts()`, and add the following line to include the Bootstrap library.

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css' );
```

Your function in the underscores's file should look like this:

```
/**
* Enqueue scripts and styles.
*/
function yourTheme_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'yourTheme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    //Enqueue bootstrap css library
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'yourTheme-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'yourTheme-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

   if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourTheme_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please DO NOT copy external stylesheets into the style.css. That is very inefficient practice.

Loading it via @import isn't recommended either. You should use [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) for CSS and [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for JS

Here is the right way to do it. Add this function to the functions.php of your theme.

```
/**
 * Load CSS and JS the right way
 *
 * @refer http://millionclues.com/wordpress-tips/load-css-and-js-the-right-way/
 */
function mcabl1226_load_css_and_js() {
  // Load Boostrap CSS
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

  // Load Theme's style.css
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  // Load Boostrap JS
  //wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mcabl1226_load_css_and_js' );
```

You would most likely need Bootstrap JS as well. Un-comment the appropriate line in the above function for that.

On a side note, if you want a very minimal starter theme to develop with Bootstrap, you can checkout my [Bootstrap starter theme](https://github.com/arunbasillal/MillionClues-Starter-Theme).